# Lambda container images complain about entrypoint needing handler name as the first argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

When I run an AWS Lambda container (Docker) image, for example:

```
docker run public.ecr.aws/lambda/java bash
```

I get the following error:

```
entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument
```

What should the handler name be?

Comment: Also, if you _do_ actually just want to shell in and run bash, you can do it like this: 
`docker run --entrypoint bash -it public.ecr.aws/lambda/java`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends what the language is of the runtime. For example, if it is NodeJS, then the handler name should look like:

```
"app.handler"
```

If it is Java, then it should look like:

```
"com.example.LambdaHandler::handleRequest"
```

The image will look for them in `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` so you will need to make sure that your code (or compiled code) is copied to that folder when you build the image, for example:

```
COPY target/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
```

Comment: it this for the CMD or ENTRYPOINT ?

Comment: @bobmoff it's CMD.
ENTRYPOINT is `/lamda-entrypoint.sh` so we pass in the _command_ of "handler" to the script.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I wanted to use the lambda image in gitlab-ci.
The solution was to override the base image entrypoint by adding the following line to my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
```

Note that this means the image will not be usable in Amazon's lambdas anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Guys in the thread are right, i stucked at the same place with my Node.js small script.

So, for me the right solution was adding `ENTRYPOINT ["/lambda-entrypoint.sh", "helloWorldFunction.handler"]`

Docker :

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14
COPY helloWorldFunction.js package*.json ./
RUN npm install
ENTRYPOINT ["/lambda-entrypoint.sh", "helloWorldFunction.handler"] 
CMD [ "helloWorldFunction.handler" ]
```

> lambda-entrypoint.sh is already placed in aws base image, don't need
> to add it manually

helloWorldFunction.js :

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return "Hello World!";
};
```

Also, **in case you are deploying it using visual studio** and AWS Toolkit - clear "image-command" field in your aws-lambda-tools-default.json as it overrides docker's CMD